# Issue integrating Node js with dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have created a Google Dialogflow agent, now I am trying to integrate it with a node js app so that I can create a custom UI for the chatbot.

I have followed the instructions in the document...
Enabled API for the project, generated the JSON key.

Below is my code:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');

/**
 * Send a query to the dialogflow agent, and return the query result.
 * @param {string} projectId The project to be used
 */
async function runSample(projectId = 'br-poaqqc') {
  // A unique identifier for the given session
  const sessionId = uuid.v4();

  // Create a new session
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: "./br-poaqqc-51d2d712d74f.json"
  });
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
  // The text query request.
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
        text: 'hi',
        // The language used by the client (en-US)
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
    },
  };
  // Send request and log result
  try {
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log('Error getting response',err)
  }
  console.log(responses);
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
  if (result.intent) {
    console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
  }
}

runSample();
```

There seems to be some certificate error. Below is the log:

```
Error getting response Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:175:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:341:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:304:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:116:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:155:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:141:18)
    at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:457:14)
    at D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\channel.js:225:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
}
(node:1632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: responses is not defined
    at runSample (D:\PV\Codebase\chatbot-ui\app.js:35:15)
(node:1632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1632) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The issue is lies around the sessionClient sending the request object to the dialogflow API. Beating my head over it for the past couple of hours. :/
Any clue where the issue is? 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you have responses out of your try block.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const config = require('./config'); // your JSON file

if(!config.private_key) throw new Error('Private key required')
if(!config.client_email)throw new Error('Client email required')
if(!config.project_id) throw new Error('project required')

const credentials = {
    client_email: config.client_email,
    private_key: config.private_key,
};

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(
    {
        projectId: config.project_id,
        credentials
    }
);

async function runSample(projectId = 'br-poaqqc') {
    // A unique identifier for the given session
    const sessionId = uuid.v4();

    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(config.project_id, sessionId);
    // The text query request.
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: 'hi',
                // The language used by the client (en-US)
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
        },
    };
    // Send request and log result
    try {
        const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        console.log(responses);
        console.log('Detected intent');
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
        console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
        if (result.intent) {
            console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error getting response', err)
    }

}

    
 runSample();
```

Don't seems any issue but i think issue was with try block.
Make sure you are with internet connection if trying from local and your firewall is not blocking `googleapis`

Comment: The console.log statement in the catch block is executed...yeah so obviously the issue lies in line where I am sending the request. But I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: sorry I missed out your code. But well I just tried your code out, it's still throwing the same error

Comment: please check you are getting creaditionls , put a console.log

Comment: Got the same error again:
`Error getting response Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
}`

Comment: Any idea what **SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain** indicates ?

Comment: I followed the instruction in the below document to generate the key: [link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup#getting_the_service_account_key) Could the issue be somewhere in this part?

Comment: can you check your local system, ? is time and date and everything perfect ?

Comment: have you tried deplying on server and run test there?

Comment: time and date in my system is fine. I didn't yet try deploying it in server, since it hasn't even worked in my local. It's not a problem with the Dialogflow agent, as I tried embedding the agent as an iframe into my react app, it works fine with both default responses and fulfillment calls to node api deployed in Heroku.

Comment: Hi Nikil, The issue was not to do with the code, the firewall was blocking the 'googleapis.com' domain. I deployed the app in Heroku server and it worked fine. :)

Comment: sure thanks. just updated, in case if someone look for

Answer (score 0):

the issue was not to do with the code, the firewall was blocking the 'googleapis.com' domain. I deployed the app in Heroku server and it worked fine. :)

For anyone who ponders around the same issue and ends up here, make sure its not a firewall issue. Cheers!